# Using Firestore DB with swift 4.0, saving to the database creates a random character document each time I authenticate

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an iPhone app in swift 4.0. I'm connecting over to Firestore, which currently works. The problem that I'm having is that a random character is document is created each time a user is authenticated. I want to change this so the email address is the registered document in the DB so the next time I login with the same credentials its uses the same document.

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(fromURL: “*****************”)
let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
let db = Firestore.firestore()
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
var checkBtnTitle:Bool = true


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
            btnLogOut.title = "LogOut"
            btnLogin.title = "Login"
            var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
            ref = db.collection("Solicitor").addDocument(data: [
                "userID": currentUser?.email! as Any,
                "Name": currentUser?.displayName as Any
            ]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            btnLogOut.title = "Login"
            btnLogin.title = ""
        }

      // google signin
       GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.uiDelegate = self
```

[image: Image of DB and random generated character]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your assistance on this one. I finally was able to get it to save... I didn't need the 'ref =' part in the DB.

```
 let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
 let businessEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email!
 db.collection("Solicitor").document(businessEmail!).setData([
```

On a side note, im still getting the auto-generated ID as well as the document ID (email address) of the user. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to stop this behaviour?

Comment: How is `Auth.auth().currentUser?.email!` different from the `currentUser?.email!` in my answer?

Comment: It’s not mate. It was the reference to the DB which was the issue.

Comment: I'm confused. You answer doesn't show any change in how you initialize the reference to the DB.

Comment: You see the first line in the original sample code, ‘ref = db.collection’.... the database did not need to be referenced. Removal of the ‘ref =‘ resolved the error

Answer (score 1):

When you call `addDocument()` Firestore create a new document with an auto-generated ID. If you want to control the ID of the document, you should use the `document()` and `setData()` methods. For example:

```
ref = db.collection("Solicitor").document(currentUser?.email!).setDate(data: [
    "userID": currentUser?.email! as Any,
    "Name": currentUser?.displayName as Any
])
```

For more on this, see the Firebase [documentation on adding documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).

Comment: Thank you Frank, that makes sense.... I've tried to add this but im receiving the following error 'Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'' any thoughts? I tried looking at the support documentation too.

Comment: Did you search for that error message? I expect that the `currentUser?.email!` causes that, but am never completely sure about the correct Swift incantation.

Comment: I did mate, im still searching for the right syntax. been struggling with this one for a bit now. any other suggestions?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892462/value-of-optional-type-string-not-unwrapped-did-you-mean-to-use-or it should be `document(String(currentUser?.email!))`

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for your assistance on this one. I finally was able to get it to save...